# Chaining calls together with shared pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

This is probably a "best practice" question, but I wanted to be sure I was going about this the right way.

I have the following class:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClassPtr;

class MyClass final : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass> {
public:
    /* ctors/dtor ommitted */

    MyClassPtr method1() {
         // does something
         return shared_from_this();
    };

    MyClassPtr method2() {
         // does something
         return shared_from_this();
    };

}; // eo class MyClass
```

This was because I wanted to easily chain calls together:

```
MyClassPtr ptr(myClassFactory.createMyClass());

ptr->method1()->method2()->methodX();  // etc...
```

Is this a suitable use for the `shared_from_this()` idiom?  Are there any gotchas I am unaware of, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why keep copy constructing shared pointers (which is fairly expensive because it requires atomic increments)? Why not return a naked pointer if this is the sole purpose?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, well that is indeed my question.  Whilst the sole purpose is, indeed, to chain the calls together - I was concerned about a naked pointer suddenly being returned.  Hence my question :)  Is this "smell"?

Comment: Why not use references. What you are trying to do sounds like an implementation of the [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: A more common idiom for chaining, which does not have a naked pointer smell (if you see it as one) would be to return a reference to `*this`, so that you'd have `ptr->method1().method2().methodX();` or `obj.method1().method2().methodX();`.

Comment: @mkaes, believe it or not, I was avoiding references because of the syntax change from `->` (when the smart pointer is first dereferenced) to `.` on subsequent calls.  This exercise is purely visual/ergonomical.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not just implementing `operator->` to accomplish the chaining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function call chaining is typically done by returning a reference to the object:

```
MyClass& method1() {
     // does something
     return *this;
};
```

Using `shared_ptr` to do it implies that you expect the only use of `MyClass` to be having it wrapped up in a `shared_ptr`. In fact, if anybody creates a `MyClass` with automatic storage duration and calls one of your methods, you're going to have a problem because when the returned `shared_ptr` is destroyed, it will try to `delete` your object. Of course, you can't `delete` a object with automatic storage duration.

I generally think that `enable_shared_from_this` should only be used if your class is providing a static factory function to generate `shared_ptr`s to itself and its constructors are private. This prevents anybody from creating an object of this type with automatic storage duration.

Nonetheless, most people would *expect* a reference to the object if they're going to do function chaining. Then at least they can do this:

```
MyClass foo;
foo.method1().method2();
```

Instead of:

```
MyClass foo;
foo.method()->method2();
```

Comment: I agree.  It's just that, as I mentioned in the comments, but it looks more like:  `MyClassPtr foo;  foo->method().method2()` and I wanted the operators to be uniform (e.g. all `->`) to avoid confusion.

Comment: But, I think you are right - after giving it some thought.  If one expects chaining to work using references then perhaps the first deference can just be ignored as the rest will follow suite.

Comment: You can always use `(*ptr).method1().method2();` to avoid the initial `->`

Comment: @Moo-Juice If they have a pointer to your object, then they understand that they'll need to use `->` to access a member. By default people should be thinking about objects and not pointers. After all, they could just do `(*foo).method1().method2();`.